# Thread not running

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a java program which implements runnable. In the body, I have `Thread animator = new Thread();` and then `animator.start();` The problem is that the `run()` method of my program does not execute. **Am I missing something**?

Comment: Post enough of your real code so that we can see how all the parts are defined and invoked.  Without that this isn't a real question.

Comment: Are you passing the object that implements runnable to the new Thread constructor?

Comment: How do you connect the run method of your program to the animator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said java program which implements runnable.

In that class ( name say Animator) body you have written

```
Thread animator = new Thread();
animator.start();
```

If i am not wrong

pass runnable class instance, here i think it would be `this` while creating thread

```
Thread animator = new Thread(this);
animator.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try in this way

```
public class BackgroundActivity {

/**
 * Attempts to execute the user activity.
 * 
 * @return The thread on which the operations are executed.
 */
public Thread doWork() {
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Background Task here");
        }
    };

    // run on background thread.
    return performOnBackgroundThread(runnable);
}

/**
 * Executes your requests on a separate thread.
 * 
 * @param runnable
 *            The runnable instance containing mOperations to be executed.
 */
private Thread performOnBackgroundThread(final Runnable runnable) {
    final Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                runnable.run();
            } finally {
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    return t;
}
```

}

Finally the doWork() method from your main method

```
 /**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BackgroundActivity ba = new BackgroundActivity();
    Thread thread = ba.doWork();

    //You  can manages thread here
}
```

Hope, It will help you.